# Hangman Game Python Error

Tags: python

I m trying to create the hangman game in python, but got following error
when I tried to run the file.

guess = input("\nEnter your guess: ")

File string", line 1, in module

Please let me know if you know the solution to fix this error

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# imports
import random

# constants
HANGMAN = (
"""
------
|    |
|
|
|
|
|
|
|
----------
""",
"""
------
|    |
|    O
|
|
|
|
|
|
----------
""",
"""
------
|    |
|    O
|   -+-
|
|  
|  
|  
|  
----------
""",
"""
------
|    |
|    O
|  /-+-
|  
|  
|  
|  
|  
----------
""",
"""
------
|    |
|    O
|  /-+-/
|  
|  
|  
|  
|  
----------
""",
"""
------
|    |
|    O
|  /-+-/
|    |
|  
|  
|  
|  
----------
""",
"""
------
|    |
|    O
|  /-+-/
|    |
|    |
|   |
|   |
|  
----------
""",
"""
------
|    |
|    O
|  /-+-/
|    |
|    |
|   | |
|   | |
|  
----------
""")

MAX_WRONG = len(HANGMAN) - 1
WORDS = ("OVERUSED", "CLAM", "GUAM", "TAFFETA", "PYTHON", "HARDWICKE", "BRADLEY", "SHEFFIELD")

# initialize variables
word = random.choice(WORDS)   # the word to be guessed
so_far = "-" * len(word)      # one dash for each letter in word to be guessed
wrong = 0                     # number of wrong guesses player has made
used = []                     # letters already guessed


print("Welcome to Hangman.  Good luck!")

while wrong < MAX_WRONG and so_far != word:
    print(HANGMAN[wrong])
    print("\nYou've used the following letters:\n", used)
    print("\nSo far, the word is:\n", so_far)

    print("\nOnly use one letter values, more than one letter at a time does not work at this time")
    guess = input("\nEnter your guess: ")
    guess = guess.upper()

    while guess in used:
        print("You've already guessed the letter", guess)
        guess = input("Enter your guess: ")
        guess = guess.upper()

    used.append(guess)

    if guess in word:
        print("\nYes!", guess, "is in the word!")

        # create a new so_far to include guess
        new = ""
        for i in range(len(word)):
            if guess == word[i]:
                new += guess
            else:
                new += so_far[i]              
        so_far = new

    else:
        print("\nSorry,", guess, "isn't in the word.")
        wrong += 1

if wrong == MAX_WRONG:
    print(HANGMAN[wrong])
    print("\nYou've been hanged!")
else:
    print("\nYou guessed it!")

print("\nThe word was", word)

input("\n\nPress the enter key to exit.")
```

Comment: When you have an error, debug it.

Comment: If you want help, at the very least provide a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (for a start, nobody needs to scroll through 100 lines of ASCII art) and the full error traceback.

Comment: This code runs fine in python3.

Answer (score 1):

```
  guess = raw_input("\nEnter your guess: ")
```

It should be raw_input, not input.

Comment: Also \n needs to be in quotations. as in '\n'.

Comment: no, that code looks like python 3 and input is correct in python 3.

Comment: It is python3 code, but the only conversion it needs to translate it to python 2.x is as suggested here, but make sure you change all instances of input() to raw_input(), if you're wanting it to run under python 2.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. It works fine now in python 2.7 once I changed all the input to raw_input.